# How are JavaScript/JSON based OData calls authenticated?

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, rest, odata

I'm new to OData (most everyone is I think).

If I have an OData service, how do I secure it from unauthorized use?  I'm looking at using WS-Trust/SAML, or standard authentication if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a related article.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astoriateam/odata-and-authentication-part-3-clientside-hooks)